# How do you mock Environment interface?

Tags: spring, mocking, spring-test

I am trying to test my service which looks like :

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Service
public class MyService {
@Autowired Environment env;
...
...
}
```

How do I mock Environment Interface, or else how do I create one?

Answer (score 30):

Spring provides mocks for property sources and the environment. Both of these can be found in the `org.springframework.mock.env` package of the `spring-test` module.

- [`MockPropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/env/MockPropertySource.html): available since Spring Framework 3.1
- [`MockEnvironment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/env/MockEnvironment.html): available since Spring Framework 3.2

These are briefly documented in the reference manual in the [Mock Objects](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#mock-objects-env) section of the testing chapter.

Answer (score 6):

Using Mockito, you should be able to do it somewhat like the code below. Note that you need to either provide accessors so that you can set the Environment field at runtime. Alternatively, if you only have a couple of autowired fields, it can be cleaner to define a constructor where you can inject the Environment.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;

public class MyServicetest {

    // Define the Environment as a Mockito mock object
    @Mock Environment env;

    MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // Boilerplate for initialising mocks 
        initMocks();

        // Define how your mock object should behave
        when(this.env.getProperty("MyProp")).thenReturn("MyValue");

        // Initialise your service
        myService = new MyServiceImpl();

        // Ensure that your service uses your mock environment
        myService.setEnvironment(this.env);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        // your test
    }

}
```

Comment: what if i dont want to mick the env, i want to use the existing ebv, with all the existing properties, I dont want to rewrite all the properties

Comment: erm ... you did ask how to mock the environment ... :-/

Comment: This worked for me, should be the correct answer. Must `initMocks()` first.

Answer (score 3):

> Implementation Class has @Autowired Environment env; So when you are running >JUnit test case you implementation class should have a constructor like below:

```
public class SampleImpl{
@Autowired
Environment env
public SampleImpl(Environment envObj){
this.env = envObj}
}
```

> your Junit Test class should be as follows:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
public class SampleTest {   

     @Mock Environment env;

     @Before
      public void init(){
          env = mock(Environment.class);     
          when(env.getProperty("file.location"))
            .thenReturn("C:\\file\\");        
      }

          @Test
          public void testCall()throws Exception{
              SampleImpl obj = new SampleImpl(env);
              obj.yourBusinessMethods();

          }
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks Steve.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. I get null for the env variable declared.

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring based test you can use: `@ActiveProfiles` so activate some Profile (but this is not a mock)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("test.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("myProfile")
public class ProfileTest {

  @Autowired
  MyService myService

  @Test
  public void demo() {
      assertTrue(myService.env.acceptsProfiles("myProfile"));
  }
}
```

---

But I you need a mock then write your own or use a mocking framework (Mokito or JMock). `Environment` has an sublass `AbstractEnvironment`, where you just need to override `customizePropertySources(MutablePropertySources propertySources)` methode

```
@Override
protected void customizePropertySources(MutablePropertySources propertySources) {
            Properties properties = ....
    propertySources.addLast(new MockPropertySource(properties));
}
```